# What's going wrong with context menu's Save Attachment in Apple email

Tags: macos, email, attachments

Apple email will *Save Attachments* to a folder of my choice, when I use **File / Save Attachments** from the menu at the top of its window.  However, if I use the context menu for the attachment icon (i.e. two fingered tap on the touchpad), and choose *Save Attachment*, the attachment will not be saved to a folder of my choice.  It is saved to some sort of temporary folder.

What's going wrong here?

For example, with a PDF file attachment I can use the context menu and do *Save Attachment* and try to save to e.g. `~/Documents/email attachments`.  I will not be able to find it there with Finder.  But with Spotlight I can find the file and open it in Preview.  Then, in Preview, I can move the file to `~/Documents/email attachments` (with File, Move To).

I'm using **Mail.app** Version **7.3** (1878.2) under OS X **10.9.3** (13D65) on a **MacBook Air** 13 (Mid 2013).

Comment: Firstly. I am not having this problem. Mine works fine. I am on the latest versions of Mail and OS X. Secondly Where are the files actually being saved??

Comment: I just did a test.  The attachment went to "/Users/alanwehmann/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail Downloads/AFFC296B-F7FC-4A80-A566-73E40DE48FAF".  I could view it there with the terminal application.

Comment: Your experience led me to try a few more tests.  From these, I conclude that the problem is the presence of a space character in the folder name.  Unix shells have problems with such folder names--if they are not "escaped".  Something similar is occurring here.

Comment: While true for unix systems. This should not be the case when using this menu in Mail.app.

Comment: Please do a test of trying to save an attachment to a folder with a space in its name, using a secondary click on the attachment and choosing Save Attachment from the context menu that pops up--as I've described.

Comment: This works as expected for me.

Comment: I have the same issue. Further for certain attachments I get "file name can not exceed 32 chars" which is absolutely ridiculous. Mail is definitely broken. Too sick to report errors. What works is to open attachment in preview and ave from there >:-(

Comment: I'm now at OS X 10.10.3, email 8.2,  and  things have changed for the better.  If I go to the header of an email having attachments, I'm offered an iconized menu that allows me to save attachments to the folder of my choice.  That seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.10.3, email 8.2 seem to have fixed the problem. If I go to the header of an email having attachments, I'm offered an iconized menu that allows me to save attachments to the folder of my choice. That seems to work.